# Design Patent - Having all 7 drawings / figures on 1 page

Tags: design-patent, patent-drawings

Would it be acceptable to have all the drawings aka "the 7 standard views" for my design patent on a single page if they all fit well. The design is not very big, and I am able to fit all 7 figures on 1 page.

Here is an example of what I mean (for obvious reasons I will not be sharing the actual drawings)

[image: example of the 7 figures]

Comment: I’m not sure why avoiding a patent attorney protects your design.

Comment: Why waste money paying someone else for a process you can learn yourself, plus when you learn the process and have the time experience you can charge others to prepare their patents..  I've known people who spent tens of thousands to attorneys, for a process that can cost less than 1,000 if your a micro entity

Comment: It is not legal to help others prepare, file, and prosecute a patent for someone else before the USPTO without being a registered practitioner. Design applications are not as hard as utility applications but there are still many ways to irrevocably screw it up. A professional might charge $1500 to $2000 for a design patent. From your question, I do not think you very near being knowledgable yet.  If you have a scientific/engineering educational background and plan to study enough to do a good job, you should take the patent bar exam and be legit as a patent agent (no need to be an attorney)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes that may be something I am interested in doing down the road, I am in the learning stage, right now I am looking to file a patent myself, versus pay a lawyer, before moving on to possibly take the patent bar exam, you need to start somewhere. Plus I am not flush with cash to pay another person $1,500 - $2,000 to just file some simple paperwork. This is why  I am avoiding a patent attorney.

Comment: It might not end up being simple paperwork. One of my first cases was a design patent application with a poor drawing. The examiner said it was rejected as not clearly showing the claimed item. She said the figure needed to be changed to have clarity. However, she said when there was clarity it was very likely that "new matter" would have been added in making the clarification. New matter is not allowed. A very real catch-22

Comment: I see! Thank you for your wisdom, I remember reading you can't add shading once submitted, as it counts as new matter, I think the drawings are very well executed, I researched shading patterns and discovered what the different symbols mean, It is an extremely simple design made out of metal, I used a cross shading effect because I read you can't use solid black shading, unless it's for a specific thing, I did the 7 standard views in CAD and then had to do some post processing in Photoshop to achieve the shading effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  many figures can be on one sheet. There is no need to use multiple sheets but if you have more than one figure per sheet you need to be careful that everything is correctly drawn under the USPTO rules to be seen as individual figures. If you look at older patents you will see many figures per sheet. However, making the figures small might hurt clarity and since there is no cost to use seven sheets rather than one sheet, there is no benefit to squeezing it together. The patent office has a very good [guide to drafting design patents](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/patent-basics/types-patent-applications/design-patent-application-guide).